# Spring MVC validation ignored

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC app on Tomcat. I'm trying to add validation in it.
For some reason my validation is ignored and not checked.

Here is my POJO

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;
public class Goal {

    @Range(min = 1, max = 15)
    private int minutes;

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }
}
```

And controller

```
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("goal")
public class GoalController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "addGoal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updGoal(@ModelAttribute("goal") @Valid Goal goal, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println(goal.getMinutes());

        System.out.println(result.hasErrors());

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "addGoal";
        }

        return "redirect:addMinutes.html";
    }
}
```

But even if I try to put any negative values as "minutes" there no errors produced.

**Added configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xlab.ice.mvc.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/pdfs/**" location="pdf"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basename="messages"/>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" p:defaultLocale="en"/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="0"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: You us your configuration.

Comment: Do you have a Bean Validation Implementation (Hibernate Validation for example) in your application? Do you have configured something (please post the spring configuration for the web stuff)

Comment: Please confirm if there is a bean validation implementation present in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is simple.
Validation libraries must be placed into classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please also confirm that you have a `JSR 303 implementation` in your classpath - say `hibernate-validator jar` files.

You need `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to enable jsr-303 validation, This is needed for the @Valid annotation to actually do anything.

try adding `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in servlet context XML if not done.

**schemaLocation** the mvc entry should contain these two:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
```

Comment: I think in the absence of <mvc:annotation-driven/>, the Spring MVC request dispatching mechanism (by use of @Controller/RequestMapping annotations) would not work so it seems we can safely assume it's present.

Comment: I have <mvc:annotation-driven /> in my config. Also I have "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER** : In the absence of complete relevant controller code and the suspicion that Validator library might be missing in classpath, here is a small test to just check the configuration. You can use this very quickly to find if all configurations are in place with just removing the session attribute part.

Let's give it a try. To simplify testing with a REST Client and also incomplete code I have not used SessionAttributes. Also there is Hibernate validator library on my runtime classpath. Also I have used ResponseBody annotation to let the Spring automatically convert the String to response text without making use of alternate view technology (like jsp).

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;
public class Goal {

    @Range(min = 1, max = 15)
    private int minutes;

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }
}
```

Then my controller

```
@Controller
public class GoalController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addGoal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String updGoal(@ModelAttribute("goal") @Valid Goal goal, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println(goal.getMinutes());

        System.out.println(result.hasErrors());

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "Errors !";
        }

        return "No Errors !";
    }
}
```

Hitting the application with a rest client on `http://localhost:8080/testApp/addGoal` with POST parameters as `minutes=1` gives me response as `No Errors !` while with `minutes=-1` gives me `Errors !`

Comment: It works for you, congratulations. But how does this help as an answer?

Comment: Bart - I have tried to keep the configuration in my answer as close as possible to the question because the code shared , especially the controller is not complete. Since SessionAttributes are in picture, controller method for GET request and method if any annotated with @ModelAttribute is missing. Secondly in the absence of complete code, by using my code it can be verified easily that appropriate validator library is really in classpath and necessary configuration are in place. So IMHO this can definitely help as a pointer till required code is provided.

Comment: @Bart - I have added more information to understand how this might help as an answer

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I meant. You're just posting a solution that works for you without knowing or understanding the problem that OP has. Your update didn't change that unfortunately.

Comment: Let us then wait for @ICE to see if this could help debug his problem or he comes up with additional info. I was of the opinion if someone does not actually know what is his problem is then other can chip in with a working solution and help him backward. If someone is having difficulty in finding the actual root cause then may be your idea of waiting is better. If he knew the actual cause he would have not posted here for our attention.